# How can I replace a mechanical switch with an electrical switch?

Tags: switches, mechanical

The following [switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iruhD.jpg) in the attached picture is as follows: pin 1 and 2 connected all the time. when switch is pressed pin 3 is connected as well to pin 1 and 2 (all pins are connected.

[image]

How can I replace the above mechaniccal switch with an electrical switch? Should I use a MOSFET? Can my [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEvwB.jpg) work?

[image]

When the Arduino is LOW, the gate is open and pins 1,2 are not connected to pin 3. When Arduino is HIGH, the gate is closed and pins 1,2 are connected to pin 3

Comment: Please show a schematic and indicate voltages, polarities and currents.

Comment: I added a schematics. I am not sure what voltage is. I think the it 12V. the think I try to switch electrically is a kawwasaki motor for children

Comment: *Can my schematic work?* <-- just think about it, you have three wires (R, Y and B) going to the microswitch in your picture and, that means it's a changeover contact so, how can a single MOSFET produce a changeover contact? Your schematic cannot work and, realistically, no schematic can be assumed to work without defining input and output voltages and currents. Your best bet is an electromechanical relay and buying a multimeter to measure the voltages and currents.

Comment: Do your pins 1,2,3 have any voltage(s) potential? I guess they do. If they dont have any voltage, the mosfet wont be able to switch on/off. In order to switch a mosftet, you need to bias its gate with a voltage that is reference to either the mosfet's drain or source voltage. Therefore drain or source voltages should have some voltage. What is the voltage of your pins in reference to GND? You also need to find the GND of your device. (probably its a car and the GND should be the battery?) My wild guess: black is GND, red is a higher voltage (12V from battery maybe?).

Comment: Find out how high is the power of the "kawwasaki motor for children" and calculate the current. (Power/12V = current)
Then you should add 10 times of this current, because the starting current is always much higher. (The FQP30N06L is a 60V / 32A MosFET. Possibly you need some in parallel.)  Measure the voltage of the red, yellow and black cable, use as reference the minus-pole of the battery. Write a better schematic of all the components of this device with the battery, engine, switch, electronic, lamps and show it here to the people.

Comment: I could not find the power in the motor manual: https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/00989pr-1056.pdf